# Monitoring networks and switches

Tags: networking, monitoring, performance-monitoring, snmp, network-monitoring

I'm new to this area when it comes to monitoring services and hardware devices. Is there anything specific I need to know?

1) Are some hardware devices more compatible then others? Like, will some not have SNMP built in?
2) When working with SNMP is it as easy as just plugging the devices IP into the web based monitoring application?
3) Is there anything from experience you have to share with me to help make my job of learning easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Some devices will have more in-depth SNMP queries built in than other, in general, professional switches like Cisco or Juniper have good support.
2. That would depend on what application you are using. Observium for instance has a lot of default queries on board for Cisco. Sometimes you will need to manually add the queries and script the output yourself. Munin is very easy and you can add custom statistics.
3. Make sure that before setting up your environment you write down what you want to monitor and what output you want to have (planning is key). Then set up a test environment before production. Try not to exclude anything from your original plan.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best piece of advise to give you is this: Don't monitor anything that you don't actually really care about. Don't configure alerts for thresholds that don't actually indicate a problem. Too often I see valuable monitoring solutions installed in an environment that either blast out so many alerts that the staff ignore them completely or I find the alerting features were turned off by a frustrated admin. The most important piece of the puzzle in implementing a successful monitoring solution is to decide what really constitutes a problem and monitor and alert on only those events.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at third-party network monitoring tool such as WhatsUp Gold or Spiceworks. Personally, I'm more of a fan of WhatsUp Gold. It will monitor not only the networking devices, but servers as well. Supports SNMP, WMI, etc.